# Integrating Angular 2 with Spring without web.xml

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

Hi I'm trying to integrate Angular 2 with Spring. I want to avoid the manual way of copying contents of dist folder everytime inside webapp while compiling. I'm trying to do it directly through pom.

My project pom looks like this :

```
 <!-- Plugin to execute command "npm install" and "npm run build" inside 
            /angular directory -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>angular</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>temp</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- It will install nodejs and npm -->
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v8.9.1</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>5.5.1</npmVersion>
                        <nodeDownloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
                        <npmDownloadRoot>http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/</npmDownloadRoot>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <!-- It will execute command "npm install" inside "/angular" directory -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <!-- It will execute command "npm build" inside "/angular" directory 
                    to clean and create "/dist" directory -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Plugin to copy the content of /angular/dist/ directory to output 
            directory (ie/ /target/transactionManager-1.0/) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <!-- <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/</outputDirectory> -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/angular/dist</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

My Initializer.java looks like this :

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    System.out.println("IN Initializer : onStartup");
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

}

 private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.tour.config");
        return context;
    }
```

And appConfig looks like this :

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver  resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}

 @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
    }
```

But on hitting the url index is not  loaded. 
P.S. I cant use web.xml hence welcome-file tag can't be used either. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Edit : Added code structure screenshot [code-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcMSs.png)

**Edit 2: I have solved the problem by extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter instead of WebMvcConfigurationSupport. However WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated now. Any leads on how to tackle it will be appreciated. Thanks.**

Comment: add your code structure screenshot

Comment: @lucumt i have editted and added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

I keep Angular and Spring apps in two separate projects. To automate the deployment of the dist dir I use a 4-line npm script.

I showed how to do it in this presentation: https://youtu.be/k8r76d8QzXs?t=2237

Comment: Is this your pom? https://github.com/yfain/springboot/blob/master/server/pom.xml I cant find the 4line npm code? 

also i'm not using spring boot

Comment: npm scripts are not in pom, but in package.json on the client:
https://github.com/yfain/springboot/blob/master/client/package.json

Comment: @YakovFain: great presentation. your work implies to have angular app as main frontend shown... What update do you recommend for just adding an angular app as a sub project, into a spring mvc app, and have the build cmd include both server and angular subapp? (The current app has a different main front end, and want to provide a link that should redirect to the new angular subapp, in new window/tab)

Comment: @j4v1If you need to open the link in a separate tab/window, there's nothing special you need to do. Just add a link that points at the main HTML file of your deployed Angular app, and the browser will load it. Adding an Angular widget to the page written in other technologies is not as straightforward. There's an experimental project Angular Elements that should allow this.